# Non detection 3G/4G mu736 huawei card at ini

Tags: wifi-hardware-switch

Why always my Kubuntu non detect my 3G/4G Card? Always, when I turn on my computer, I need to do this steps to turn on the 3G/4G Integrated card mu736 huawei - model [http://consumer.huawei.com/solutions/m2m-solutions/en/products/tech-specs/mu736-en.htm][1]

The steps that I need to follow in the Konsole are:

```
ALL ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/victorsnk
modprobe option
echo "03f0 521d" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
usb_modeswitch -H -v 03f0 -p 521d -s 10
```

the result thrown is:

```
victorsnk@victorsnk-HP:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for victorsnk: 
root@victorsnk-HP:/home/victorsnk# cd script
root@victorsnk-HP:/home/victorsnk/script# ./modem.sh
./modem.sh: línea 3: ALL: orden no encontrada
Note: No target parameter given; success check limited
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 002 on bus 002
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
     Product: HP hs3110 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Device
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Send old Huawei control message ...

Check for mode switch (max. 10 times, once per second) ...
 Wait for original device to vanish ...
 Original device can't be accessed anymore. Good.
 (For a better success check provide target IDs or class)
 Original device vanished after switching

Mode switch most likely succeeded. Bye!
```

*Note: I had to created a script to resume the process, but I can't get start it at the ini when I start the computer. Anybody knows how can I solve it?

My OS is Kubuntu 16.4 LTS (64x) and my kernel 4.14.0-041400-generic

Thanks!